# Why doesn't this R function either work or throw an error? (Scoping issue?)

Tags: r, scope

This builds a simple data frame, and applies a function to both of its rows.
However,

```
name2num[[name]] = uid
```

fills in `name2num`, while

```
num2name[uid] = name
```

doesn't fill in `num2name`.

```
numbers = c(1,2)
names = c('a', 'b')
df = data.frame(numbers, names)
name2num = new.env()
num2name = integer(nrow(df))
f = function(row) {
    uid = as.integer(row[1])
    name = row[2]
    name2num[[name]] = uid
    num2name[uid] = name
}
```

These are my tests:

> apply(df, 1, f)
>   [1] "a" "b"
>   name2num[['a']]
>   [1] 1
>   name2num[['b']]
>   [1] 2
>   num2name
>   [1] 0 0

I could understand this if `num2name` inside the function were a local variable, but if it were, I should get an 'object not found' error message.

I know that it would be better to write the function to pass the results back, but I want to know what R is doing and why it neither throws an error, nor writes to num2name. Why doesn't it either write to the global variable, or throw an object not found error, like it would if I used the name of a variable not defined in the calling environment?

```
f = function(row) {
    uid = as.integer(row[1])
    name = row[2]
    name2num[[name]] = uid
    foo[uid] = name
}
```

> apply(df, 1, f)
>       Error in foo[uid] = name : object 'foo' not found

Comment: A function in R captures the environment in which it has been defined. So, when an object is used in the body, R looks for it in the function environment and, if it's not found, in the calling environment. However, if that's the case, the object is copied and so the modifications are not visible outside the function. This applies to every object but the `environment`s which are modified by reference. That's the reason why an object is modified and the other is not in your code. For instance, calling the function `a<-function() iris<-iris[1:50,]` *won't* modify `iris`.

Comment: @nicola--Thanks; you should write that as an answer rather than as a comment.